# 3 monitors with asus zenbook ux410uq

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, usb-c

I have Asus Zenbook ux410uq, and i would want to work with 3 external monitors, but i have only one HDMI port, and one usb c-type. I am wondering, can i plug one monitor with usb c-type to hdmi adapter, and other monitors with hdmi splitter? Will it works correctly? Or maybe one HDMI splitter which would split my hdmi to 3 or 4? If not, is there any solutions to plug 3 monitors to this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a USB C multiport hub that will only use the USB C port as the source and it will extend to your three monitors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I tried and it is possible, i just needed usb 3.0 -> HDMI and usb c-type -> HDMI adapters.

Comment: You might get more recognition / reputation / validation for your answer if you provided more details.